# Routes in Ruby On Rails and RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I usually work with Java or Clojure and I have not done much Ruby programming, so I am grateful for your patience. I have just created a new site, with Ruby 2.1.5, Rails 4.1.8 and the latest version of RefineryCMS.

If I do:

bundle exec rake routes

then I see:

```
new_signup GET    /refinery/users/register(.:format) refinery/users#new

signup POST   /refinery/users/register(.:format) refinery/users#create
```

but if I point my browser at:

0.0.0.0:3000/new_signup

or:

0.0.0.0:3000/refinery/new_signup

I get 404.

Where should I point my browser to reach these routes?

If I point my browser directly at:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/refinery/users/register
```

I get redirected to:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/refinery/login
```

I can guess a few places where I might need to change the settings to fix that, but if you could suggest a place to look, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `bundle exec rake routes` the output is in the format:

```
route_name  HTTP_VERB  path/to/access/this/route   controller#action
```

When you look at:

```
new_signup GET    /refinery/users/register(.:format) refinery/users#new
signup     POST   /refinery/users/register(.:format) refinery/users#create
```

...this is showing you two routes, one named "new_signup" and the other "signup", both which are accessed via `/refinery/users/register.html` (where `.html` is the format and is optional because it is in parenthesis). If it's a GET request it will route to the `new` action in the  `refinery/users` controller, and if it's a POST request then its routed to the `create` action.

Given what @manfergo25 said, I think since you already have a user in your database, the `new_signup` action is now redirecting you to the login route to prevent other users from signing up to gain access to your admin.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

RefineryCMS manage this internaly. When redirect to /refinery/login is because you already create the superuser(admin).

if you want to register again and do not remember username and password, do this:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop
bundle exec rake db:migrate
go to --> http://0.0.0.0:3000/refinery and register
```

After register it will give you an error (RefineryCMS bug) but go to --> http://0.0.0.0:3000/refinery again and login with your new username and password

Answer (score -1):

```
new_signup GET    /refinery/users/register(.:format) refinery/users#new

signup POST   /refinery/users/register(.:format) refinery/users#create
```

there are 3 parts, you should understand:

1. `new_signup` - this is named route, used in controllers, views, etc, and you cant use it in browser, it will throw 404 for sure
2. `/refinery/users/register(.:format)` this is what you should type in browser
3. `refinery/users#new` - this is controller and action for route, where refinery - its namespace of controller and users - controller and #new - action

Answer - you need to go /refinery/users/register to see sign up form